# Prevent getting old updates from Telegram Bot API using a web hook

Tags: telegram-bot

I'm writing a Telegram bot and I'm using the [official bot API](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api). I've got a webhook server that handles requests and sends a `200 OK` response for every request.

Before the server stops, the webhook is detached so Telegram does not send updates anymore. However, whenever I turn the bot on and set the webhook URL again, Telegram starts flooding the webhook server with old updates.

Is there any way I can prevent this without requesting `/getUpdates` repeatedly until I reach the last update?

Here's a heavily simplified version of how my code looks like:

```js
var http = require('http'),
    unirest = require('unirest'),
    token = '***';

// Attach the webhook
unirest.post('https://api.telegram.org/bot' + token + '/setWebhook')
    .field('url', 'https://example.com/api/update')
    .end();

process.on('exit', function() {
    // Detach the webhook
    unirest.post('https://api.telegram.org/bot' + token + '/setWebhook')
        .field('url', '')
        .end();
});

// Handle requests
var server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' })
    res.end('Thanks!');
});

server.listen(80);
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you server starts up you can record the timestamp and then use this to compare against incoming message `date` values. If the date is >= the timestamp when you started...the message is ok to be processed.

I am not sure if there is a way you can tell Telegram you are only interested in new updates, their retry mechanism is a feature so that messages aren't missed...even if your bot is offline.

Comment: Yes: date is a field of message object: https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#message In webhooks mode, there is not way to filter by update_id/date: https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#getting-updates so filter-out old dates is the solution IMMO. BTW, I wrote a webhooks handler in Ruby: http://www.github.com/solyaris/BOTServer

Answer (score 4):

The best way is to use `update_id` which is a specific number that increases on every new request (i.e. update). How to implement it?

First off, let's start with the following [anonymous class](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.anonymous.php) (using PHP7):

```php
$lastUpdateId = new class()
{
    const FILE_PATH = "last-update-id.txt";
    private $value = 1;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->ensureFileExists();
        $this->value = filesize(self::FILE_PATH) == 0
            ? 0 : (int)(file_get_contents(self::FILE_PATH));
    }

    public function set(int $lastUpdateId)
    {
        $this->ensureFileExists();
        file_put_contents(self::FILE_PATH, $lastUpdateId);
        $this->value = $lastUpdateId;
    }

    public function get(): int
    {
        return $this->value;
    }

    public function isNewRequest(int $updateId): bool
    {
        return $updateId > $this->value;
    }

    private function ensureFileExists()
    {
        if (!file_exists(self::FILE_PATH)) {
            touch(self::FILE_PATH);
        }
    }
};
```

What the class does is clear: Handling the last `update_id` via a plain file.

**Note**: The class is tried to be as short as possible. It does not provide error-checking. Use your custom implementation (e.g. use `SplFileObject` instead of `file_{get|put}_contents()` functions) instead.

Now, there are two methods of getting updates: Long Polling xor WebHooks (check [Telegram bot API](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api) for more details on each methods and all JSON properties). The above code (or similar) should be used in both cases.

**Note**: Currently, it is impossible to use both methods at the same time.

### Long Polling Method (default)

This way, you send HTTPS requests to Telegram bot API, and you'd get updates as response in a JSON-formatted object. So, the following work can be done to get new updates ([API](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#getupdates), [why using offset](https://core.telegram.org/bots/faq#long-polling-gives-me-the-same-updates-again-and-again)):

```php
$botToken = "<token>";

$updates = json_decode(file_get_contents("https://api.telegram.org/bot{$botToken}/getUpdates?offset={$lastUpdateId->get()}"), true);

// Split updates from each other in $updates
// It is considered that one sample update is stored in $update

// See the section below
parseUpdate($update);
```

### WebHook Method (preferred)

Requiring support for HTTPS POST method from your server, the best way of getting updates at-the-moment.

Initially, you must enable WebHooks for your bot, using the following request ([more details](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#setwebhook)):

```
https://api.telegram.org/bot<token>/setWebhook?url=<file>
```

Replace `<token>` with you bot token, and `<file>` with the address of your file which is going to accept new requests. Again, it must be HTTPS.

OK, the last step is creating your file at the specified URL:

```php
// The update is sent
$update = $_POST;

// See the section below
parseUpdate($update);
```

From now, all requests and updates your bot will be directly sent to the file.

### Implementation of `parseUpdate()`

Its implementation is totally up to you. However, to show how to use the class above in the implementation, this is a sample and short implementation for it:

```php
function parseUpdate($update)
{
    // Validate $update, first
    // Actually, you should have a validation class for it

    // Here, we suppose that: $update["update_id"] !== null
    if ($lastUpdateId->isNewRequest($update["update_id"])) {
        $lastUpdateId->set($update["update_id"]);
        // New request, go on
    } else {
        // Old request (or possible file error)
        // You may throw exceptions here
    }
}
```

Enjoy!

**Edit**: Thanks to @Amir for suggesting editions made this answer more complete and useful.

Comment: for webhook you cannot use `offset` and `getUpdates` . I used your code without that `$updates` but the same problem still goes on...

Comment: @Amir Yes, in the case of WebHooks, the requests will be sent to your file directly; and thus, you should use `$_REQUEST` superglobal instead.

Comment: thanks for your attention, could you update your answer and add the webhook case support to it ? @MAChitgarha

Comment: @Amir I've just edited the answer; in other words, I did a complete rewrite. Hope it helps.

Comment: there is a problem with looking for `update_id` inside the `$_post` and it's not defined there. BTW I would appreciate if you check out my last question and if you have any recommendation for that I would be really happy to hear it. and definitely a thumbs-up for this answer and the answer I would get in my own question :))

Comment: @Amir Actually, it should work. I haven't worked with WebHooks for a long time, so maybe there is something missing in my answer. However, I guess your problem is something else. Do you get updates at all (i.e. is $_POST variable set)?

Comment: yes , I get updates by `file_get_contents('php://input');
`

Comment: @Amir No, what I mean is to log the request data into a file and analyze it. What the JSON object looks like? You should receive a valid Telegram bot API JSON object, otherwise, the problem is something else, AFAIK.

Comment: there was no problem with the JSON object and the problem was with my code that i wasn't passing the `update_id` in a right way.
BTW you'll get a fatal error on running your file because at the moment you are passing a NULL to `isNewRequest()` but that's ok when the request is sent from telegram and you have a true `update_id`. 
thumbs-up  :))

Comment: @Amir Thanks for your comments and attention! Mentioning this, thanks to you, I've edited my answer to be more useful.

Answer (score 3):

In the webhook mode, Telegram servers send updates every minute until receives an OK response from the webhook program.
so I recommend these steps:

1. Check your webhook program that you specified its address as url parameter of the `setWebhook` method. Call its address in a browser. It does not produce an output to view, but clears that probably there is no error in your program.
2. Include a command that produces a '200 OK Status' header output in your program to assure that the program sends this header to the Telegram server.

Comment: can you provide some lines of code?
i tried what you meant, but I keeps fetching responses../

Comment: in php you can use `header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");`

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue, then I tried to reset the default webhook with

https://api.telegram.org/bot[mybotuniqueID]/setWebhook?url=

after that, i verified the current getUpdates query were the same old updates but I sent new requests through the telegram's bot chat

https://api.telegram.org/bot[mybotuniqueID]/getUpdates

when I set up my webhook again the webhook read the same old updates. Maybe the getUpdates method is not refreshing the JSON content.

NOTE:
in my case, it was working fine until I decided to change /set privacy bot settings from botfather

Answer (score 0):

Telegram API has the method [`deleteWebhook`](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#deletewebhook) with the parameter `drop_pending_updates`, which does exactly what topic starter needs.